# Pandas use and operator in LOC function

Tags: python, pandas, operator-keyword

i want to have 2 conditions in the `loc` function but the `&&` or `and` operators dont seem to work.:

df:

```
business_id  ratings  review_text
xyz          2        'very bad'
xyz          1        'passable'
xyz          3        'okay'
abc          2        'so so'
```

mycode:
i am trying to gather all `review_text` whose ratings are `< 3` and have `id = xyz` into a list

```
 id = 'xyz'
mylist = df.loc[df['ratings'] < 3 and df[business_id] ==id,'review_text'].values.tolist()
```

i should get:

```
['very bad','passable']
```

This code doesnt work and i get the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

how do i use the `and` operator correctly here?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need `&` for `and` logical operator, because need element-wise `and`, see [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
id = 'xyz'
mylist=df.loc[(df['ratings'] < 3) & (df['business_id'] == id),'review_text'].values.tolist()
print (mylist)
['very bad', 'passable']
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `query`

```
df.query('ratings < 3 & business_id == @id').review_text.tolist()

["'very bad'", "'passable'"]
```

Answer (score 2):

use ~ for not logical operation

For example:

```
train.loc[(train['MiscVal'] == 0) & (~train['MiscFeature'].isna())]
```